# Set Representation with tabular form, the number of elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

In set theory, the order in which elements are listed is immaterial but elements must not be repeated. So {1, 1} is not permitted.

Then the number of elements in set {1,a} (a is real number) is 1 or 2 or both possible?

Comment: The number of elements of $\{ 1,a \}$ is two if $a \ne 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It is not really illegal to write $\{1, 1\}$, but duplicates in sets defined by lists are ignored.  So, in your case, if $a = 1$, you have one element; otherwise you have two.